# Match first 6 digits from variable with many strings in Array ( PHP )

Tags: php

I am trying to make a comparasion or ( matching ) using preg_match and other helpful stuff ...

I had this Array:

```
$ids = array("93215018" ,"93215019" ,"93215020" ,"93215022" ,"93215025" 
,"93215040" ,"93215050","93215079" ,"93215070" ,"93215021" ,"93935018" 
,"93935019" ,"93935020" ,"93935022" ,"93935025" ,"93935040" ,"93935050" 
,"93935079" ,"93935070" ,"93935021" ,"93415018" ,"93415019" ,"93415020" 
,"93415022" ,"93415025" ,"93415040" ,"93415050" ,"93415079" ,"93415070" 
,"93415021" ,"93515018" ,"93515019" ,"93515020" ,"93515022" ,"93515025" 
,"93515040" ,"93515050" ,"93515079" ,"93515070" ,"93515021" ,"93615018" 
,"93615019" ,"93615020" ,"93615022" ,"93615025" ,"93615040" ,"93615050" 
,"93615079" ,"93615070" ,"93615021" ,"93715018" ,"93715019" ,"93715020" 
,"93715022" ,"93715025" ,"93715040" ,"93715050" ,"93715079" ,"93715070" 
,"93715021");
```

and I made a variable that gets the ID from an input form using HTML:

Now, When the user enter his ID, the PHP file should check if the fist 7 digits he entered matches any of the first 7 digits defined in the array.

I've used these stuff and it didn't work:

```
$first7 = substr($uid, 7);
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $firstid = substr($id, 7);
    $pos = strpos($firstid, $first7);
    if ($pos !== true) {
        header("Location: success.php"); 
    } 
}
```

And:

```
$first6 = substr($uid, 2);
foreach($ids as $id) {
$firstid = substr($id, 2);
if (preg_match("/$firstid(.*)$/", $first6, $results)){
header("Location: success.php"); }
```

And :

```
if ($firstid==$first6){
```

And:

```
 if (preg_match('/$id/', $first6)){
```

Still didn't work..

Anyone have an idea to how to do it?? I am using PHP 5.6 ..

Comment: "it didn't work" is _not helpful_. What _did_ happen?  In what way did the result differ from what you wanted?  Did you get errors?  If so, what were they?

Comment: strpos will never return `true`. It'll return `FALSE` if nothing is found or an index of the found position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a naive solution like the following:

```
$first7 = substr($uid, 0, 7);

$matched = false;

foreach ($ids as $id) {

    if (substr($id, 0, 7) === $first7) {
        $matched = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is working when I use it without else condition, right after adding else condition it because always do the else without checking the if condition.. my else is simple else { header("Location: failed.php");

Answer (score 1):

`substr($uid, 7);` isn't how you get the first 7 characters. The second argument of [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is the starting position, not the length.

Also, if you've gotten the first seven characters of `$uid`, and the first seven characters of an array entry, you don't need to use `strpos` at all. You can just check if they're equal.

You can use this to get the first seven characters of `$uid`:

```
$first7 = substr($uid, 0, 7);
```

Then you can find all matching ids.

```
$matches = preg_grep("/^$first7/", $ids);
```

Or redirect after you find the first one:

```
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $firstid = substr($id, 0, 7);
    if ($firstid === $first7) {
        header("Location: success.php");
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver Me too! Although if there are a lot of values it may be better to use something like the other answer that breaks after finding one match.

Comment: It worked perfectly that way ... Also the answer below of yours also worked .. Thank you guys <3

Comment: After adding else statement for the if condition, its not doing the else statement without checking the if condition.. is there any idea to fix that?

Comment: @BHappy If you want to redirect somewhere else if it is _not found_, don't put that in an `else` block. Just put it _after_ the `foreach` loop. If it's found during the loop, it will redirect immediately, and if it makes it to the end of the loop without finding it, it will redirect to the other location then.