# Post data from HTML input form with PHP action file without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML input form, and a PHP file. Now I am trying to execute the PHP file and return the result without refreshing the page. So, I've used javascript to do that. But now after using javascript, the $_POST[uid] is unable to get the ID that user entered, so the PHP file returns the else condition.

I have this HTML form :

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <span>
        Sign in System
    </span>
    <div data-validate = 
 "ID is required">
        <input id="uid" type="text" name="uid" 
 placeholder="Please enter your ID number">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
                
    <input type="button" id="searchForm" 
onclick="SubmitForm();" value="Signin" />
```

and this is the used javascript code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function SubmitForm() {
    var uid= $("#uid").val();
    $.post("test.php", { uid: uid},
        function(data) {
            alert("Sorry.. " + data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

and This is my PHP Code:

```
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['uid'];
$first7 = substr($uid, 0, 8);
$ids=Array(Some Array Values)
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if (substr($id, 0, 8) === $first7){
        header("Location: success.php");
    }
    else{ 
        echo "Entered ID is Wrong"; break;
    }
}
```

Now the result always give me the else condition which shows an alert box says: Entered ID is wrong .. which doesn't even able to check if it is correct and redirect to success.php

Any Idea ??

Comment: You did not send `uid` on your `$.post()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var idd = $("#uid").val();
```

you dont have a `idd` name in the input, its `uid`

and in php

```
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['idd'];
```

Comment: Hello, I made an Edit to: var uid = $("#uid").val(); and everything changed from idd to uid.. and left the php without changes.. it also returns the else condition...

Comment: that is a problem with your if condition, not of sending data, that is a different case, you need to put it as a different question, accept the answer and post a new question

Comment: Why it is a problem in my if condition?? Before adding the javascript code, with the traditional way after using action="test.php" and it redirects to the php file, the file is working perfectly and the data sent and already been checked in the if condition.. it only fails checking the entered data after using javascript.

Comment: check what is being passed by printing the uid and first7 then you will understand

Comment: After using echo, both of $uid and $id are printed.. the input passed to the php is correct, and the function is correct.. Please check my question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017605/match-first-6-digits-from-variable-with-many-strings-in-array-php/49017943#49017943

Comment: Got that .. the issue caused by else condition, Is there anyway to put else correctly with if within foreach loop ?

Comment: in this case you cannot, as you are redirecting once the id are matched

Comment: temporarily, I did that using preg_grep .. without foreach loop .. and its working .. I hope to find a solution for the foreach if else conditions .. :( .. Thank you for your help